# Query from comment table which is related to itself?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comment table which is related to itself with id as PK and parent as FK. It's one level hierarchical storage data somehow. Each comment can have just one parent which doesn't have parent or parent=NULL. It means just root comment can have a reply.

This is my table fields:

```
id   user_id   post_id  comment   parent  username
```

For simplicity I store username in this table and we don't need to join user_id with user table.
I want show each comment and a link to the parent comment if it has parent, it's important show last inserted comment first.

I try this query which is not giving me what I want:

```
SELECT COMMENT . * , c1 . *
FROM `comment`
LEFT JOIN COMMENT c1 ON c1.parent = comment.id
```

Comment: i do it , LEFT JOIN COMMENT c1 ON comment.parent = c1.id

Comment: What it's giving you than?

Comment: Since you are joining the same table, which has the same column names, you will have issues trying to access both row values by column name. You could either access them by numerical index - `0`,`1`,etc. - OR use column name aliases on 1 or both of the rows.

Comment: Try with `SELF JOIN`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

if id is an autoincrement try somth like this

```
SELECT COMMENT . * , c1 . field1 AS parent_field1, c2.field2 AS parent_field2 /*and so on*/
FROM `comment`
LEFT JOIN COMMENT c1 ON c1.parent = comment.id
ORDER BY id DESC
```